# TextBox.Text binding error when running on Windows XP

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, windows-xp

I've noticed an interesting error in WPF, and I wondered if anyone else has also seen it, and if so, how did they get around it?

I have a `Window`, and within in is a `GroupBox`, within which is a `TextBox`. The `DataContext` on the `GroupBox` is set to an object within my program, and as a result a binding on the `TextBox` is set like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Directory_Data}" IsReadOnly="True"
         Name="dataPath_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
         Height="23" Margin="6,3,3,3"/>
```

On Windows 7 (which I develop on), this works fine, and I had no reason to even think twice about that line of XAML. However during some testing on Windows XP (with .NET4.0 installed), opening this `Window` caused the whole program to crash, with this error:

> EventType: clr20r3, system.invalidoperationexception.

It took me ages to work through the code until I finally narrowed it down to the XAML line above.

Changing `TextBox` to a `Label` (and changing the `Text` property to `Content`) prevented this crash and the program worked as planned; it just seems to be a `TextBox` error.

Although it is possible to just switch `TextBox` to `Label` (given that in my case it will be `ReadOnly` anyway), I would prefer the `TextBox` for appearance sake. It may be that I have to update the `Text` property manually from the code behind.

Anyway, mainly I just wanted to point out this problem in case anyone else encounters something similar. Any thoughts on why this is though would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there more information on the error? Like a stacktrace or something? Also, have you tried on another XP-based machine? (to make sure it's not just a corrupt installation of the framework)

Comment: There are some numbers in the error box; I wasn't thinking they'd be very meaningful but I can add them if you like? Yes, I've tried it on two machines. It was actually someone testing it for me on an XP machine that found the error, at which point I tried it myself on another one and managed to replicate it.

Comment: No unfortunately the numbers won't be of any use, at least for me. Is the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event triggered if you subscribe to it? You may be able to gather more information this way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Comment: Can you turn on CLR exceptions in the debugger to get a stack trace when this is thrown? I guess it might be possible that view data gets initialised / bound in a slightly different order due to the different renderers used by WPF in XP vs Win7.

Comment: Hi Gaz, I can't do the CLR exceptions as the XP PC does not have Visual Studio, so I can't run programs in the debugger on that. However, the AppDomain.UnhandledException has solved the problem... It shows that "A TwoWay or OneWayToSource" binding cannot work on a read-only textbox, and so changing it to OneWay solves the problem. It is interesting though that this issue only arose on Windows 7 and not XP. I wish I'd known about this event before, it would have saved me ages! Thanks KooKiz!

Comment: `Changing it to OneWay solves the problem, though why this occurs on XP and not Windows 7 I am not sure` Are you sure you're using the same version of the .NET framework on the Windows XP and Windows 7 computers? I know for instance that .NET 4.0 WPF applications can have a slightly different behavior when running on .NET 4.5.

Comment: Both computers claim to be using 4.0.30319, although mine is listed as a "Multi-Targeting Pack", whereas the XP one has a "Client Profile" and "Extended". Do you think this might cause an error even though the version number is the same?

Comment: Do *not* add an answer to the *question*, add the answer *as an answer*.

Answer (score 0):

From suggestions in the comments, I implemented `AppDomain.UnhandledException` as outlined here. I put the code just before:

`app.InitializeComponent();`

`app.Run();`

This then was made to output to a `MessageBox`). By then recreating the problem I received the following message:

"A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on a read-only property" of the `TextBox`.

Changing it to `OneWay` solves the problem, though why this occurs on XP and not Windows 7 I am not sure. Making the `TextBox` not `ReadOnly` would also work, though in my case I want it to remain `ReadOnly`.